# NSProgressIndicator in NSStatusItem

Tags: cocoa, nsview, menubar, nsstatusitem, nsprogressindicator

I have NSStatusItem with a custom NSView which shows images.
Whether the menu is opened or not it show different images just like that:

```
 isMenuVisible = NO;

- (void)awakeFromNib {

statusItem = [[NSStatusBar systemStatusBar] statusItemWithLength:NSVariableStatusItemLength];
[statusItem retain];

dragStatusView = [[DragStatusView alloc] init];
[dragStatusView retain];
dragStatusView.statusItem = statusItem;
[dragStatusView setMenu:statusMenu];
[dragStatusView setToolTip:NSLocalizedString(@"Menubar Countdown",
                                             @"Status Item Tooltip")];
[statusItem setView:dragStatusView];
[dragStatusView setTitle:@"11"];
}

- (void)drawImage:(NSImage *)aImage centeredInRect:(NSRect)aRect{
NSRect imageRect = NSMakeRect((CGFloat)round(aRect.size.width*0.5f-aImage.size.width*0.5f),
                              (CGFloat)round(aRect.size.height*0.5f-aImage.size.height*0.5f),
                              aImage.size.width, 
                              aImage.size.height);
[aImage drawInRect:imageRect fromRect:NSZeroRect operation:NSCompositeSourceOver  fraction:1.0f];
}

- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)rect {
// Draw status bar background, highlighted if menu is showing
[statusItem drawStatusBarBackgroundInRect:[self bounds]
                            withHighlight:isMenuVisible];




if(isMenuVisible) {
    [self drawImage:image2 centeredInRect:rect];
}else {
    [self drawImage:image1 centeredInRect:rect];

}}
```

(Of course this is not everything, but i hope all the relevant code to understand my problem)

Now i want to show a NSProgressIndicator in this NSView (in this NSStatusItem) if an upload is proceeding which means
1. Set the NSProgressIndicator when upload starts
2.Received something ? ==> Hide NSProgressIndicator show the image again.

How would i solve this ?

Please help me. Thanks

Comment: nobody ? i hoped to find someone here you could help me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is the solution for View based status item.

```
NSStatusBar *bar = [NSStatusBar systemStatusBar];
self.theItem = [bar statusItemWithLength:NSVariableStatusItemLength];
self.statusView = [[NSView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 40, 20)];
NSProgressIndicator* progress = [[NSProgressIndicator alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 40, 20)];
[progress setIndeterminate:NO];
[self.statusView addSubview:progress];
self.theItem.view = self.statusView;
```

You can also draw a progress bar your self in Menu based status item
on progress change you can simply change the image of your status item.

```
- (void) updateIconWithProgress:(float)aProgress
{
    NSImage* image = [NSImage imageNamed:@"small_icon_16_16.png"];
    NSImage* img = [image copy];
    [img lockFocus];

    NSRect rect = NSMakeRect(2, 4, 12.0*aProgress, 8.0);
    [[NSColor blueColor] set];
    [NSBezierPath fillRect:rect];

    [img unlockFocus];
    [self.theItem setImage:img];
}
```

p.s. The code was written for ARC (Automatic Reference Counting) so there is no retain or release.