# Animating a NSStatusItem

Tags: cocoa, animation, core-animation, nsview, nsstatusitem

I have a custom view in an NSStatusItem object.
This view displays icons. It's also able to show a progress, but you have to call `[self.statusitemview setProgressValue:theValue];`
I have a set of icons, and it chooses the right one using this value.

This seems very jerky, because the executed process doesn't send updates all the time.
So I would like to animate this.

I would like to call the animation like you can with other cocoa-controls:
[[self.statusItemView animator] setProgressValue:value];

If that's at all possible

What is the proper way to do this?
I wouldn't want to use an NSTimer.

**EDIT**

The images are drawn using the drawRect: method

Here's the code:

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
{
    if (self.isHighlighted) {
        [self.statusItem drawStatusBarBackgroundInRect:self.bounds withHighlight:YES];
    }

    [self drawIcon];
}

- (void)drawIcon {
    if (!self.showsProgress) {
        [self drawIconWithName:@"statusItem"];
    } else {
        [self drawProgressIcon];
    }
}

- (void)drawProgressIcon {
    NSString *pushed = (self.isHighlighted)?@"-pushed":@"";
    int iconValue = ((self.progressValue / (float)kStatusItemViewMaxValue) * kStatusItemViewProgressStates);
    [self drawIconWithName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"statusItem%@-%d", pushed, iconValue]];
}

- (void)drawIconWithName:(NSString *)iconName {
    if (self.isHighlighted && !self.showsProgress) iconName = [iconName stringByAppendingString:@"-pushed"];
    NSImage *icon = [NSImage imageNamed:iconName];
    NSRect drawingRect = NSCenterRect(self.bounds, icon);

    [icon drawInRect:drawingRect fromRect:NSZeroRect operation:NSCompositeSourceOver fraction:1.0 respectFlipped:YES hints:nil];
}


- (void)setProgressValue:(int)progressValue {
    if (progressValue > kStatusItemViewMaxValue || progressValue < 0) {
        @throw [NSException exceptionWithName:@"Invalid Progress Value"
                                       reason:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"The value %d id invalid. Range {0 - %d}", progressValue, kStatusItemViewMaxValue]
                                     userInfo:nil];
    }

    _progressValue = progressValue;
    [self setNeedsDisplay:YES];
}

- (void)setShowsProgress:(BOOL)showsProgress {
    if (!showsProgress) self.progressValue = 0;
    _showsProgress = showsProgress;

    [self setNeedsDisplay:YES];
}
```

It has to be possible somehow.
Since standard controls from Apple are drawn using the drawRect:, but have smooth animations...

Comment: How is your status item view defined? Does it have a layer? What does setProgressValue: do?

Comment: Unfortunately not, I implemented it using drawRect:

Comment: and setProgressValue just set's the an ivar and sends setNeedsDisplay: to update it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To animate custom properties, you need to make your view conform to the [`NSAnimatablePropertyContainer`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSAnimatablePropertyContainer_protocol/Introduction/Introduction.html) protocol.

You can then set up multiple custom properties as animatable (in addition to the properties already supported by `NSView`), and then you can simply use your views' `animator` proxy to animate the properties:

```
yourObject.animator.propertyName = finalPropertyValue;
```

Apart from making animation very simple, it also allows you to animate multiple objects simultaneously using an `NSAnimationContext`:

```
[NSAnimationContext beginGrouping];
firstObject.animator.propertyName = finalPropertyValue1;
secondObject.animator.propertyName = finalPropertyValue2;
[NSAnimationContext endGrouping];
```

You can also set the duration and supply a completion handler block:

```
[NSAnimationContext beginGrouping];
[[NSAnimationContext currentContext] setDuration:0.5];
[[NSAnimationContext currentContext] setCompletionHandler:^{
    NSLog(@"animation finished");
}];
firstObject.animator.propertyName = finalPropertyValue1;
secondObject.animator.propertyName = finalPropertyValue2;
[NSAnimationContext endGrouping];
```

For a standard `NSView` object, if you want to add animation support to a property in your view, you just need to override the `+defaultAnimationForKey:` method in your view and return an animation for the property:

```
//declare the default animations for any keys we want to animate
+ (id)defaultAnimationForKey:(NSString *)key
{
    //in this case, we want to add animation for our x and y keys
    if ([key isEqualToString:@"x"] || [key isEqualToString:@"y"]) {
        return [CABasicAnimation animation];
    } else {
        // Defer to super's implementation for any keys we don't specifically handle.
        return [super defaultAnimationForKey:key];
    }
}
```

I've created a simple [sample project](https://github.com/rkeniger/Animating-View) that shows how to animate multiple properties of a view simultaneously using the `NSAnimatablePropertyContainer` protocol.

All your view needs to do to update successfully is make sure that `setNeedsDisplay:YES` is called when any of the animatable properties are modified. You can then get the values of those properties in your `drawRect:` method and update the animation based on those values.

Comment: Thank you so much! I can't believe that it's that simple

Answer (score -1):

I have answered similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11385499/nsprogressindicator-in-nsstatusitem/12572267#12572267)

You can't animate custom properties with animator, but you can write custom animation if you need, though it's not best idea.

Updated (Custom Animation):

```
- (void) scrollTick:(NSDictionary*) params
{
  static NSTimeInterval timeStart = 0;
  if(!timeStart)
    timeStart = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];

  NSTimeInterval stTime = timeStart;
  NSTimeInterval currentTime = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
  NSTimeInterval totalTime = [[params valueForKey:@"duration"] doubleValue];

  if(currentTime > timeStart + totalTime)
  {
      currentTime = timeStart + totalTime;
      timeStart = 0;
  }

  double progress = (currentTime - stTime)/totalTime;
  progress = (sin(progress*3.14-3.14/2.0)+1.0)/2.0;

  NSClipView* clip = [params valueForKey:@"target"];
  float startValue = [[params valueForKey:@"from"] floatValue];
  float endValue = [[params valueForKey:@"to"] floatValue];

  float newValue = startValue + (endValue - startValue)*progress;
  [self setProperty:newValue];

  if(timeStart)
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(scrollTick:) withObject:params waitUntilDone:NO];
}

- (void) setAnimatedProperty:(float)newValue
{
  NSDictionary* params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:self.property], @"from",
   [NSNumber numberWithFloat:newValue],@"to",
   [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0],@"duration",
            nil];

  [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(scrollTick:) withObject:params waitUntilDone:NO];
}
```

Comment: You misunderstood my question. It has nothing to do with NSProgressIndicator. I have my own property called property, which helps me to find the right icon for the current progress. But instead of setting [self.statusItemView setProgressValue:0.5]; and seeing it jump, I would like it to animate to 0.5.

Comment: You can't animate custom properties with animator. You need custom animation - i have updated my answer with custom animation example (linear).

Comment: That's not exactly what I was looking for. Yes, I understand that I can't use the animator property, but it has to be possible to do this with core-animation in some way. If necessary I can use layers. There are ways to do this, but I only got it working when drawing it, not when setting an image as content.

Comment: I don't like using timers and recursive methods, that gets buggy when you have a lot of animation, which I do.

Comment: You absolutely can animate custom properties using the `animator` proxy. See my answer.